# ViewPager with views and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm currently making a playlist of videos. The flow of this is that from a ListView, it shows the list of the videos in the playlist. Upon clicking on the video, it will open the PlaylistActivity with this layout:

**Playlist layout:**

[image: playlist layout]

**Problem:**

The videos are working fine because I can hear them being played. However, probably because I used fragments, every time I click the prev or next button the video is being played on the last opened page from the `ViewPager`.

On the custom `PagerAdapter`, I inflated the layout with a custom player and an empty `LinearLayout` container where I will add the fragment.

**PlaylistPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class PlaylistPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    List<Playlist> videos;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return videos != null ? videos.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
        View pagerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_player, container, false);
        pagerView.setTag(videos.get(position).getId());
        container.addView(pagerView);
        return pagerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    public void setVideos(List<Playlist> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Playlist getItemAt(int position) {
        if (position > -1 && position < getCount()) {
            return videos.get(position);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        if (videos != null && !videos.isEmpty()) {
            videos.clear();
            videos = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**view_video_player.xml**

```
<com.example.abd.ui.playlist.PlaylistVideoPlayerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.example.abd.ui.misc.CustomVideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/gray_holo_light" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_exit_btn_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@drawable/semi_transparent_button_bg"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
            android:id="@+id/btn_video_exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/action_done" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/yt_video_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/gray_holo_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</com.example.abd.ui.playlist.PlaylistVideoPlayerView>
```

If the url of the video is from YouTube, then I will set the visibility of the `CustomVideoView` into `GONE` and set the `LinearLayout ytVideoContainer` into `VISIBLE` so it can show the fragment.

**PlaylistVideoPlayerView.java**

```
public void bindYouTubeVideo(FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction, YouTubeVideo youTubeVideo) {
    if (videoView != null && ytVideoContainer != null) {
        ytVideoContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        videoView.setVisibility(GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_OBJ, youTubeVideo);

    YouTubePlayerFragment yt_fragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment();
    yt_fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction
            .replace(ytVideoContainer.getId(), yt_fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

A snippet of `onPageChanged()` listener of the `ViewPager`:

**PlaylistActivity.java**

```
if (url.contains("youtube.com") || url.contains("youtu.be")) {
    GetVideosDetailsByIDs getVideosDetailsByIDs = new GetVideosDetailsByIDs();
    final String youtubeId = extractYTId(url);
    try {
        getVideosDetailsByIDs.init(youtubeId);
        GetYouTubeVideosTask task = new GetYouTubeVideosTask(getVideosDetailsByIDs,
            new GetYouTubeVideosTask.VideoResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResults(List<YouTubeVideo> videosList) {
                    if (videosList != null && !videosList.isEmpty()) {
                        YouTubeVideo youTubeVideo = videosList.get(0);

                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        if (!isFinishing()) {
                            videoView.bindYouTubeVideo(fragmentTransaction,
                                    youTubeVideo);
                        }
                    } else {
                        handleGetVideoStreamFailure();
                    }
                }
            });
        task.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Failed to play the youtube video.");
        handleGetVideoStreamFailure();
    }
}
```

It seems like the fragment was not added to the current page, does this have something to do with the `AsyncTask`? or with the way I added the fragment?

Comment: which one is you adapter class to set fragment

Comment: @krishankTripathi I didn't use fragments on my list but I have a view where I have a container layout to insert the fragment. You can see my implementation of that in `PlaylistVideoPlayerView.java`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a fragment in your viewpager, you have to notify your adapter of the change. Your list of fragments needs to be updated to remove the 3rd fragment and add a new one in its place. After you've done that, you call notifyDataSetChanged in your adapter.

You could have an method  like this in your adapter:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, int index) {
    mFragmentList.remove(index);
    mFragmentList.add(index, fragment);
    // do the same for the title
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I didn't use Fragments in the custom `PagerAdapter` class because there could be some instances where I don't need to use it.